# WINE installation regarding

Tags: wine

After giving this command:

```
sudo apt-key add Release.key
```

Getting response:

```
gpg: can't open `Release.key': No such file or directory
```

and I am unable to install `wine`.

Comment: did you download the GPG key and are you sure it's in the directory you're in on the console?

Comment: I have installed playonlinux and wine installed along with it by default using application center